# Broken LED remote

Tags: electrical, lighting

My sister stepped on my 44 button LED light remote and it stopped working , Is there any way I can replace the remote by just ordering a new one or will i have to manually repair it. If so, how should i go about doing that.

Comment: Welcome to DIY. It would certainly help to know what kind of remote you have.

Comment: Manufacturer? Model #? Pictures?

Comment: It was this model specifically https://www.amazon.com/Upgraded-Strip-Lights-32-8ft-Adhesive/dp/B07QDBW84F/ref=sr_1_3_sspa?crid=26VTNWBI1MPO1&keywords=led+strip+lights+60+feet&qid=1575010193&sprefix=led+strip+lights+60+%2Caps%2C143&sr=8-3-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFWNjc1VjE5N1dZRlgmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTEwMzUyNjlUQldDSklCVUZQRDEmZW5jcnlwdGVkQWRJZD1BMDM3MzUyOFVKMzFOM0FONjRTWSZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=

Comment: All we could say would be "maybe", as the remotes may be universal, or may be configured for that specific LED strip.

Comment: if the remote looks the same it probably works the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your product is a package that bundles several products also sold separately:

- LED strip
- power supply, and
- controller/remote combo.

In particular, LED controllers are sold with their matching remote.   These are so cheap you'd be better off just buying this and attaching it.

Comment: So to clarify, I could buy just another power supply and remote since they come connected to each other?

Comment: @esher **controller** and remote. Not the thing that goes into AC power.  That box that sits between the power supply and the LEDs.  It might say "RGB control box".

Answer (score 0):

I found a ["Multi-function LED Remote Control"](https://www.pier1.com/multi-function-led-remote-control/3605163.html?scid=scplp3605163&sc_intid=3605163&s_cid=pla|Google|SC+Shopping+-+Mobile&gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=Cj0KCQiAoIPvBRDgARIsAHsCw09OrNAjRsJK4FKQ3vc72tWivs41lkcC8Km8RIrDTKqzRukSe6wAbJ0aAn9XEALw_wcB) at Pier 1 and several led light remote control apps on the Google Play store, some for free.

I've used remote control apps on my phone to test & operate other devices I don't have remotes for.

Answer (score 0):

You might browse the apps available for download to your smartphone.

Once, in a rental house, the DVD and television had a wrong brand remote which was almost totally incompatible with the devices.  Something like "power on" and "volume" worked, but nothing else did.

I was able to salvage the weekend by searching the [Play app store](https://play.google.com/store/apps) and searching for ["Visio control video"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=visio%20control%20tv&c=apps) (there are dozens!) and try a few of them.  As I recall it took three or four tries before finding one which worked "well enough".